# Easily importing all third-party packages and scripts as a common package?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I want to add an `external` package to my program which should include all recipes and third-party packages it uses. I don't want to force anyone (including myself) to install those packages, not to mention the version incopatibilities. I just
want to put them into their own subfolders and use them. They,
of course, come from various sources.

The folder structure should look like this:

```
| main.py
|---[external]
    |---[networkx]
    |   | ...
    |---[xlrd]
    |   | ...
    | __init__.py
    | recipe1.py
    | recipe2.py
```

I want to reach the packages and recipes in the following ways in my program:

```
import external
import external.xlrd
from external import networkx as nx
import external.recipe1
from external import recipe2 as magic
from external import *
```

Any package however may contain absolute imports which can result `ImportError` assuming an `external` has an empty `__init__.py`:

```
>>> import external.networkx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File ".\external\networkx\__init__.py", line 46, in <module>
    from networkx import release
ImportError: No module named 'networkx'
```

Is there an easy way to make such an external package?

Answer (score 0):

I made a function which does this. All you need to do is to put this line to the `__init__.py` of the external folder:

```
__all__ = import_all(__path__)
```

This function can use generally to import all submodules, even if they are nested, just put this to all `__init__.py` involved.

If you know a cleaner solution to the question, please share it with us! I won't accept my own answer.

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import abspath, basename, exists, isdir, join, \
    relpath, sep, splitext
from sys import path

def import_all(path__here):
    """Imports all subpackages and submodules, excluding .py
files starting with an underscore. The directories have to
have an __init__.py to get imported.

Add this line to the __init__.py:
    __all__ = import_all(__path__)"""
    result, packagepath = [], relpath(path__here[0])
    for e in listdir(packagepath):
        mod_path = join(packagepath, e)
        mod_name = splitext(basename(e))[0]
        file_to_import = (e.endswith(".py")
            and not mod_name.startswith("_"))
        dir_to_import = (isdir(mod_path)
            and exists(join(mod_path, "__init__.py")))
        if not file_to_import and not dir_to_import:
            continue
        im_str = ".".join(mod_path.split(sep)[:-1] + [mod_name])
        try:
            __import__(im_str)
        except ImportError as err:
            # In case of a subpackage countains absolute imports
            # assuming it is in the root, we put it into the
            # system path and try again.
            if abspath(packagepath) not in path:
                path.insert(0, abspath(packagepath))
                __import__(im_str)
            else:
                raise err from None
        result.append(mod_name)
    return result
```